# Python openpyxl error: BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Facing the error "BadZipFile: File is not a zip file" when loading excel workbook using openpyxl load_workbook function. How do I solve this error?

```
workbook = r'C:\Desktop\Test.xlsx'
worksheet = 'Data'


# create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(workbook, engine='openpyxl')

wb = load_workbook(workbook)
writer.book = workbook
writer.sheets = {x.title: x for x in wb.worksheets}
ws = writer.sheets[worksheet]

for i in range(len(vehicle_sales)):
    row = list(vehicle_sales.iloc[i])
    
    for j in range(len(vehicle_sales.columns)):
        value = row[j]
        ws.cell(i+2, j+1, value)
        
xl.writer.excel.save_workbook(wb, workbook)
```

[image]

Comment: It seems the file is corrupted. If you can you open this file in some office suite, try re-saving it.

Comment: Is the file a real Excel file or some text file with a fake `xlsx` extension? `XLSX` is a ZIP package containing XML files in a well-defined format. A lot of sites fake them though by generating CSV or even HTML tables with the `.xlsx` extension. Excel isn't fooled and will *import* these files as text or HTML using the user's locale settings, but every application that actually expected a ZIP will fail

Comment: Where did that Excel file come from? How was it created?

Comment: The excel file was created using Microsoft Excel. Its stored in a OneDrive folder, I'm not sure if this affects anything?

Answer (score 1):

The excel files were in read-only mode. I saved the file as a new file and load_workbook worked.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. The excel file was in editable mode. Tried saving as a new file and same error occured.